# How can I update the value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame  `df` which consists of three columns: doc1, doc2, value

I set value to 0  in all the row. I want to update the value using the jaccard similarity function (suppose it is defined).
I do the following:

```
df['value'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   sim = jaccardSim(row['doc1'], row['doc'])
   df.at[index, 'value'] = sim
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. When i print `df`, I get in `df['value']` the value 0.

How can I solve that?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Try something simple like `sim = row['doc1'] + row['doc']`. Make sure `jaccardSim` is not returning 0s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df['value']=[jaccardSim(x, y) for x , y in zip(df['doc1'], df['doc'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it making vectorized function. you should modify the `jaccardSim` to take a row of df or create a lambda wrapper function

```
jaccardSim = lambda row: jaccardSim(row["doc1"], row["doc2"])
```

```
vect_jaccardSim = np.vectorize(jaccardSim)
df['value'] = vect_jaccardSim(df)
```